# How to access dotnet core event-counters on code - publish as metrics

Tags: c#, .net-core, prometheus, grafana

I am going to publish some of the statistics provided by event-counter as metrics.
There are many pre-defined ones in the framework as we can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/available-counters).

How I can access the information (that is available through dotnet-counters)?

Comment: Are you asking the question because you don't want to use `dotnet-counters` or is there some other reason you're asking the question?

Comment: I'm asking this question because I want to have this information from dotnet-counters as metrics.

Comment: How are you trying to collect the data? Are you thinking of automating dotnet-counters or writing an application to collect and report the values?

Comment: I want to collect them by Prometheus and then show them on Grafana.

Comment: Did you see this: https://dev.to/ingvarx/monitoring-your-dotnet-service-using-prometheus-2hhn?

Comment: Yes, but so far from what I have asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available through the [OpenTelemetry packages](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/net/getting-started/). In my own applications I use the following to add OpenTelemetry metrics for the runtime and process metrics and publish them to Prometheus :

```
public static IServiceCollection AddOtelMetrics(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    string[]? names=null)
{
 services.AddOpenTelemetryMetrics(meters =>
 {
     meters.AddEventCountersInstrumentation(c =>
     {
         c.AddEventSources("rabbitmq-client");
     });

     meters.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation();
     meters.AddHttpClientInstrumentation();
     meters.AddRuntimeInstrumentation();
     meters.AddProcessInstrumentation();

     if (names != null)
     {
         meters.AddMeter(names);
     }

     meters.AddPrometheusExporter();
 });
```

The `AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation`, `AddRuntimeInstrumentation` and `AddProcessInstrumentation` add the well known meters. Other meters can be added by passing their names to `AddMeter`. EventSources can also be added, with `AddEventCountersInstrumentation` and passing the EventSource name.

```
 meters.AddEventCountersInstrumentation(c =>
 {
     c.AddEventSources("rabbitmq-client");
 });
```

Comment: The OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.EventCounters package is needed to reach the AddEventCountersInstrumentation method.